# convert const char * to struct tm under Android with C++

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I want to get a `struct tm` from a `const char *`. In order to achieve the goal I use following code:

```
CCLog("ServerTimeStamp:%s",servertimestamp);
struct tm servertime;
servertime.tm_isdst=0;
servertime.tm_gmtoff=0;
CCLog("servertime prev:{%i,%i,%i,%i:%i:%i+%i+%li}",servertime.tm_year,servertime.tm_mon,servertime.tm_mday,servertime.tm_hour,servertime.tm_min,servertime.tm_sec,servertime.tm_isdst,servertime.tm_gmtoff);
strptime(servertimestamp, "%FT%TZ", &servertime);
CCLog("servertime post:{%i,%i,%i,%i:%i:%i+%i+%li}",servertime.tm_year,servertime.tm_mon,servertime.tm_mday,servertime.tm_hour,servertime.tm_min,servertime.tm_sec,servertime.tm_isdst,servertime.tm_gmtoff);
```

But the output is:

```
ServerTimeStamp:2014-07-18T11:51:09Z
servertime prev:{24,1803363120,22,1803363016:0:1796668624+0+0}
servertime post:{24,1803363120,22,1803363016:0:1796668624+0+0}
```

Which means that `strptime` has probably done nothing. Is this function not implemented on Android under JNI (In the cocos2d-x environment, version 2.1rc0-x-2.1.4)? What would be a suitable alternative? How can I convert the `const char *` to `struct tm`?

My App is cross-platform, and the same code works perfectly under iOS (also with the environment cocos2d-x, version 2.1rc0-x-2.1.4).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean `strptime(): convert a character string to values to be stored in a tm structure` ?

Comment: You use a %F specifier. What should it do? It's not on the list here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html

Comment: @greenapps `%F Equivalent to %Y-%m-%d, the ISO 8601 date format.` from [this page](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_strptime.htm), but it seems ti be a GNU extension, maybe it is not implemented in Android.

Comment: @greenapps You were right, that was the problem. If you convert it into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the %F specifier for a date.

Comment: in case someone has the same problem, `%F` is equivalent to `%Y-%m-%d`